How can we show that a discrete signal with higher frequency component needs more number of finite samples for approximation?
To realize a finite-impulse response of a digital filter in the context of digital system control, one way is to approximate the input signal by limited number of samples and hence avoid oversized implementation of the filter which is not realistic most of the time. However, care must be taken about the number of most recent input samples that needs to be taken as if the input signal includes high-frequency component, then the number of samples needs to be large enough to accommodate the high-frequency content. This question is raised to find an analytical explanation for the argument mentioned above.

I am no expert on digital system control, but this question makes no sense to me. Perhaps try rewording things and see if you don't get some responses.

Appreciate your feedback.
